# Use different config files - decision should be made via command-line argument

Tags: python, configuration, arguments

I have a script, that uses a config file called config.py. Actually this is rather a configuration module then. Anyways: the configuration-module contains a lot of parameters and dictionaries and lists of dictionaries and so on.

In the script today it is used like this

```
import config

def main(): 
    myParameter = config.myParameter
```

Now I have another application scenario for this script that uses a related config ('config_advanced.py', but the parameters and dictionaries have different values.

My goal is now, to chose the name of the used config-modul as a passed command-line argument:

```
myScript.py -configuration config_advanced.py
```

Since the configuration-module is in the same folder than the main script, I guess I have to rename the passed configuration file to 'config.py' first. Afterwards I can perform `import config`. Otherwise, if  I used `import config_advanced, I wouldn't be able to use a call like

```
config.myParameter
```

in the main script.

Another possibility could be, to put the configuration-modules in subfolders and keep the name config.py. The passed command-line-argument will have to contain the subfolder then.

Either way I won't be able to perform the import at the top of the main file, since I have to do the argument parsing first. This isn't a technically problem, but someone said that this it at least bad pratice.

What do you think? 
What is a better way to do the trick with not much effort? 
Thanks a lot

---

Edit:
One working solution has been

```
import sys fullpath = "d:\\python\\scripts\\projectA\\configurationFiles\\" 
sys.path.append(fullpath) 
config = __import__('config_advanced')
```

Without syspath it does NOT work, so those following tries won't work:

```
config = __import__('d:\\python\\scripts\\projectA\\configurationFiles\\config_advanced')
config = __import__('d:\\python\\scripts\\projectA\\configurationFiles\\config_advanced.py')
```

Comment: Does it have to be python? Json/yaml/ini would be much easier (and safer) to work with.

Comment: You can import a module by name using the built-in [`__import__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=__import__#__import__) function and name the result `config`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! I had to append the path of the configuration file first. Or is there another way, too? This was my solution:  
`import sys`  
`fullpath = "d:\\python\\scripts\\projectA\\configurationFiles\\"`  
`sys.path.append(fullpath)`  
`config = __import__('config_advanced')`

Comment: sorry for bad formatting. According to the help two spaces should add a linebreak:
"End a line with two spaces to add a <br/> linebreak". But I guess, I am doing something wrong here

Comment: It's hard to read code in comments, and it's not possible to indent it properly, so _please_ edit it into your question instead. Code in comments should be restricted to tiny fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility that's similar to what you suggest in the question, but which doesn't need you to hide things in subfolders, is to put config_advanced.py and config_plain.py in the same folder as the main script and then dynamically make config.py a link to the actual config file you want to use.

However, martineau's suggestion is *much* simpler.

OTOH, georg brings up a very valid point, *especially* if this script isn't just for your own personal use. While using Python itself for the config data is flexible and powerful, it's perhaps a little *too* powerful. Config data should just *be* data, not live executable code. If you make a minor mistake when modifying config data you could cause havoc if it's in an executable file. And if a malicious user gets to it, there's no limit to the damage they could cause.

Bad data in a plain old data file will at worst cause a ValueError if it does something weird that your config parsing code isn't suspecting. But bad data in a live Python file could throw all sorts of nasty errors. Or even worse, it could do something evil in complete silence...

---

In reply to your comments, here's some code to illustrate the first point:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import os

config_file = "config.py"

def link_config(mode):
    if os.path.exists(config_file):
        os.remove(config_file)

    config_name = "config_%s.py" % mode
    os.symlink(config_name, config_file)

#.... parse command line to determine config_mode string, then do
link_config(config_mode)

#Now import the newly-linked config file
import config
```

If config_mode == "plain" the above code will cause config_plain.py to be imported as 'config'

and if config_mode == "advanced" it will cause config_advanced.py to be imported as 'config'

But as I said before, martineau's method is *much* simpler. And IIRC, `os.symlink` may not work on non-unix systems.

...

As for your second point, check out [the docs for the json module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: 1. I don't undestand the first point ;) - you mean, I should file-write to config.py first, so that config.py contains something like "import config_plain" and then import config?

Comment: 2. Config should only contain data: Seems valid to me :)  
I wasn't sure about the handling of lists of dictionaries, and I thought, using a python-modul as config would be the easiest apporach. I have never used json before, but it seems pretty similar to normal python dictionaries.  Anyway: Using only data in the confiuration means, that I need some parsing. So I guess I should use the config-parser modul? But how does it work to read json formatted list of dictionaries with lists with the config-parser? Is there an example somewhere?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. I have never seen os.symlink before. But I understand your point, that it might not work. So I imlemented martineau's method. I hope I did it the right way :)